# Redirection after sending mail not working | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, environment-variables, message

**What I want:**

I want to display a message when the user is redirected back to the form page after a mail is sent.

**What I am doing**

Here is the code in my *SendEmailController.php*:

```
return back()->with('success', 'Mail Sent !');
```

Here is my code in my *view/index.blade.php*:

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

I want to mention that I just followed this tutorial: https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/simple-way-to-sending-an-email-in-laravel.html

**In practice :**

Nothing is displayed, the main page remain the same and my mail is sent.

**What i tried :**

I tried setting a route as following:

In my *web.php*:

```
Route::get('/succeed', 'PagesController@succeed')
```

In my *PagesController.php*:

```
return view('index')->with('success', 'Mail Sent !');
```

When I go to http://localhost/succeed, my div is displayed.

In the end, I don't understand why I don't understand why that div don't want to show up.

***Edit***:

Tried:

```
redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Mail Sent !');
```

Not fixing the issue

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you need to use `return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Mail Sent !');`   you missing `redirect()`

Comment: thank you for responding that quickly, i just tried your answer but it is still not showing anything.

Comment: what not showning it will redirect to back page  what is your back url ?

Comment: @Dogasp did you put `return redirect()->back()...` on Pages Controller?

Comment: my back url is my main page so localhost/

Comment: @party-ring no it is on my SendEmailController

Comment: @Dogasp so in you `/` page content your `@if ($message = Session::get('success'))` code ?

Comment: Yes my `/` route redirect to index.blade.php which contain @if ($message ... code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is fixed, I had some AJAX in the background that was blocking the redirection.

Thanks you a lot for giving me answers.

Answer (score 0):

Like said above, use redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Mail Sent !');

then

use session('success')

```
@if (session('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I have already tried that solution, it didn't impoved the situation. And I am shure that the problem is not comming from my code in the index file as I have set up a route to check if the parsed variable worked and it does indeed.